# Showing unique solutions to simultaneous linear congruences exist

Tags: number-theory

Show that if $p$ is prime, then the simultaneous linear congruence

$$ax + by \equiv u \pmod{p}$$
$$cx + dy \equiv v \pmod{p}$$

has a unique solution $x, y$ modulo $p$ when $ad-bc \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: An analogue of the result is true in any field, it is basic linear algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solve it as you would an ordinary $2\times2$ linear system (i.e., using Cramer's rule). You'll end up dividing by the determinant of the matrix, hence the condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is like an ordinary system of linear equations over $\mathbf{R}$, say, except that you do not compute in the field $\mathbf{R}$, but in the field $\mathbf{Z}_{p}$.